# Atomic operation between integrated GPU and CPU

Tags: gpu, opencl

Hi I'm working on developing an application, which involves working on shared data between GPU and CPU.
I know I can do atomic operation GPU and CPU separately. And also I don't want to use event synchronized between CPU and GPU.
Is there any way/command so that I can do atomic operation on shared data between CPU and integrated GPU in OpenCL?

Comment: Why don't you want to use event synchronisation? This is one of the main reasons to use it! Sounds like premature optimisation. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: As shared data gets accessed regularly by both cpu and gpu, I thought synchronization won't be a good idea.

Comment: Well *some* form of synchronisation is essential for data shared between the CPU and GPU, otherwise you'll have data races and nasty consequences. It comes down to the access patterns, granularity of concurrency and relative overhead of different approaches. As @mogu points out, Fine Grained Shared Memory is available on OpenCL, if your app suits that model. Also consider redesigning your data structures may allow you to avoid or reduce the problem significantly.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible but there are preconditions. You'll need a device supporting OpenCL 2.0 or higher (Intel, AMD and ARM all have such devices, i dunno about Nvidia).
To get started, look [here](https://developer.amd.com/fine-grain-svm-with-examples/),[here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-20-shared-virtual-memory-overview#sync) and [here.](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/atomic_compare_exchange.html)